# Suitable to ask about how to use a particular controller?

Tags: discussion

Is it on-topic here to ask how to set up a particular controller?  This is a Resol Deltasol BX controller for my solar hot water.  I'm confused by the wording.

Comment: Hi! I moved your question from the main site to meta, because that's where on-topic questions are best asked. Personally I feel the question is on-topic, but depending on the exact question it could be more suitable on Electronics SE. In any case it is up to the community to decide if a question is on-topic and has high enough quality.

Comment: Oh, I thought I had asked on meta! Thanks